# Problema em efeito acordion simples em parágrafos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

isto é praticável? Ou possuem alguma sugestão sem plugins jQuery UI?

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="minhaclasse">
<p class="titulo">Título<br>resumo<br></p>
<p class="outros"> texto de descrição </p>
</div>
<div class="minhaclasse">
<p class="titulo">Título<br>resumo<br></p>
<p class="outros"> texto de descrição </p>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
p.titulo{ cursor: pointer}
p.outros{display:none}
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".titulo").mouseover(function(){
        $(this).siblings(".outros").css("display", "block");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim é possível.

Eu faria assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".titulo").hover(function () {
        $(this).next().toggleClass("outros");
    }, function () {
        $(this).next().toggleClass("outros");
    });
});
```

CSS

```
p.titulo {
    cursor: pointer
}
.outros {
    display:none
}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/qxmTL/)

Usando o [**.hover()**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) é possível ter uma função para quando o mouse está hover e quando saiu.
Usanto o [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) pode selecionar-se somente o proximo sibling

---

Para usar o efeito acordeão mais tradicional pode usar assim:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".titulo").on('click', function () {
        var descricao = $(this).next(); // por o elemento onde está a descrição em cache
        $(".outros").not(descricao).slideUp(); // esconder todos os que possam estar abertos menos o que está junto ao que recebeu clique
        descricao.slideToggle();  // abrir ou fechar consoante estiver aberto ou fechado
    });
});
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9SNr/)

Comment: Hum, mas eu não gostaria de adicionar ou remover a classe. Apenas mostrar/não mostrar. Na minha aplicação, eu preciso manter a classe.

Comment: @MarceloAymone, assim: __http://jsfiddle.net/n9SNr/__ ?

Comment: desta forma ficou perfeito.

Comment: @MarceloAymone, óptimo. Juntei essa opção à resposta.

Comment: Muito obrigado...

Comment: @MarceloAymone, fico contente de ter ajudado. Se a resposta resolve o seu problema pode marcar como correta.